# How can I use JavaScript to send emails instantly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to figure out a way to send emails with JavaScript. So the first thing I did was went to Google and looked up if this is possible. I found out you can use the code below to send JavaScript emails.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="emailSubject" placeholder="Type your 
            subject... "/>
            <input type="text" id="emailBody" placeholder="Type something... "/>
            <button onclick="send()">
                Send
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js

```js
const emailSubject = document.getElementById("emailSubject").value;
const emailBody = document.getElementById("emailBody").value;

function send() {
    Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "myemail@gmail.com",
    Password: "*******",
    To: "anotheremail@gmail.com",
    From: "myemail@gmail.com",
    Subject: emailSubject,
    Body: emailBody,
    }).then(
        message => alert("Sent successfully.")
    );
}
```

Why didn't this work? I check this code for any misspelled words, and found none. So can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's dev tool console for errors?

Comment: You may have copy this code from Following article
[https://pepipost.com/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-with-javascript/][1]
But you may have forgot to add https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js
In your script Most important thing is you should turn off your Google 2 step authentication.

Comment: As a tip for newbies: Always `.catch` your Promises. That way you will know what is happening.

Comment: Yes that is where I got this code from. But I turned off 2 step authentication, and I linked the JS file on line 18. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>`

Comment: @j08691 The first thing I did was check the console.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I just did that, but thank you anyway : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial there is a key difference between your implementation and the one provided. Where you are using `<button>` the example uses `<input type="button">` like below:

```
<input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="send()"/>
```

Key difference is the button you are using is submitting the form element and refreshing the page so the `send()` function is never run.

With the above in place of the button the form is never submitted and the function is called.

Comment: I have a question, why does it refresh the page and not call the function? This doesn't make sense to me. But I did make the change and now the function is being called and displaying a pop-up, but it still isn't sending the email. I check my spam folder and it wasn't there. : (

Comment: @TheBlueFlame7456 The default `type` of a button is `submit`

Comment: @j08691 I had the `allow less secure apps` setting off. I turned it on and now i can send emails with JavaScript.